# Insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint fk_dbo with Entity Framework one-to-one relation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-relationship, one-to-one

I have three entity classes. what I am trying to do is to insert data into `User` table and insert the data at the same time to the table called `Company`. and `Owner`

Here is the my code: (*as title mentioned that I am getting insert error*)

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Company.Company Company { get; set; }
          public virtual  Owner.Owner Owner { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        ...........
}

public class Company : BaseEntity
{
        [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }  
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public string Explanation { get; set;            
        ...........
}



public class Owner:BaseEntity
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("User")]

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string NameSurname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }
       ...........
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }


        User usr=new User {  
      usr.NameSureName = user.NameSureName;
        usr.Email = user.Email;
         ...........
               };

        var company = new Company
        {

            CompanyMemberShipType = CompanyMemberShipType.Free,


        };
        var owner = new Owner
        {

            CellPhone = user.CellPhone,
            Email = user.Email,
            NameSurname = user.NameSureName
        };
        usr.Company = company;
        usr.Owner = owner;
       var userresult = _userService.Insert(usr);
```

Comment: **Show us the code** that really does the insert!

Comment: That means: show what's inside `_userService.Insert(usr);`

Comment: @GertArnold I am sorry ,I clear database and create again and it fix the problem ,It seems one unwanted FK asignto Db,and stay there .thats what s the trouble thank you all.